# Searching for questions asked between two dates

Tags: support, search

How do you search for a question asked between two dates? I know the tag of the question and some words from the question body.

Comment: See also: [Add date range to “Advanced Super Ninja Search Options”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options) on meta.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [Help Center page on searching](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

- `is:question` will only return results which are questions.
- `created:yyyy-mm-dd..yyyy-mm-dd` will return results which were posted between (inclusive) the two (UTC) dates. (The `created:` option is pretty flexible, with more details described in the Help Center page linked above.)