# Access to question posts from previous years.

Tags: support, search

As far as I know, to search posts, say, from 2016, requires a tremendous amount of effort:  From the "Newest" tab on main math.se, one can search up to five pages back, and then can choose up to 7 pages back, then choose up to nine pages back, then choose ..., then choose 1201 pages back, then hit 1211 pages back, or vice versa, start from the very last post on math.se, and go back two pages at a time, to reach, say 1201.

My point is, it is an exceedingly time-consuming task.

Perhaps I've not yet discovered a simpler, more immediate approach, such as a field some where: "Go to page _____".

If there is no such functionality, are there other ways to back-track on posts from an earlier time?

If there is no such current feature, perhaps we should ask for a feature that allows this?

Comment: Some previous posts which are (to some extent) related: [Searching for questions asked between two dates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19463) and [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak.  The question that prompted my post was primarily particular year, but I think the question about searching questions asked between two dates would be tremendously helpful in narrowing the field, so to speak (especially recently).  Searching for $2017$ would yield a huge hit list.  Not so interested in searching one particular user's post within a given time range, but I can see how that would be really helpful to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, [use search modifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Specifically, `created:2016` or `lastactive:2016` should do the trick in this case.

Comment: Ironically, suggestions for search modifiers are featured under "Our model" in the help section.  Never would have thought to check there.  But still, after 7+ years, you'd think I would have happened upon this, before now!

Comment: Always have a logician on hand, I say. Or at least someone who understands basic model theory and can look at the model.

Comment: One that is not in the list and is very useful: `deleted:1`

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: But that's only for 10k users.

Comment: Yes, I just [saw that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317824/how-can-i-track-down-my-answers-to-deleted-questions). Nevertheless, it helped me find some deleted answers I didn't want to lose.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the other answer, it is also possible to navigate to a particular page via editing the URL: For example,

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=42

will take one to the 42nd page.

Appending `&sort=newest` would make sure that the questions are sorted by age. Otherwise, ones last choice would determine which criterion is used.

Comment: OMG!  Handy, indeed!  I've bookmarked this page (question and answers).