# How can I search questions asked a specific period of time?

Tags: support, search

As stated in the title,  I do not know how to do that... I see only things arrange questions like "newest,  votes, active"...Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [Searching for questions asked between two dates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19463) and
[How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is information regarding this in the [How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page.

You can do the following searches, for example:

> created:2014..2017

will return all questions which were created from 2014-01-01 to 2017-12-31.

You can refine this to

> created:2014-04..2017-05

for a precision of months, or

> created:2014-04-01..2017-05-21

for a precision of days.

You can couple this with other criteria. (You will find that even small intervals of time yield a very high number of questions.)

For example,

> created:2014-04-01..2016-05-03 score:4 [differential-geometry] curvature

returns questions asked between 2014-04-01 and 2016-05-03, with score at least 4, in the [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) tag and with "curvature" in its contents.