# How to see the questions posted in a particular month in a particular year in a specific tag

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, search

I want to see the questions posted in a particular month in a particular year in a specific tag. For example, I want to see all questions posted in [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) in September month of 2016. Could anybody please tell how to do that?

Thanks in advance. Any help/suggestions will be useful.

Answer (score 10):

> For example, I want to see all questions posted in [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) in September month of 2016.

You can used built-in-search for this. The modifier [created:2016-09-01..2016-10-01](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-09-01..2016-10-01) returns only posts from September. (I have added one more day to be on the safe side - and also to make this easier to modify.) If you are interested just in one month, you can simply use [created:2016-09](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-09). (You can check that this indeed returns the same number of results as [created:2016-09-01..2016-09-30](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-09-01..2016-09-30), For more on how to use `created` see Advanced Search Options linked below.)

You can add `is:q` to restrict this [just to questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-09-01..2016-10-01+is%3Aq).

And you can refine the search expression further - in this case you are interested in [questions from a specific tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2016-09-01..2016-10-01+is%3Aq+%5Bsequences-and-series%5D). But apart from tags you can also include keywords, further modifiers, etc.

See also:

- You can find some basic overview of built-in-search here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29266)
- If you are interested in further modifiers (similar to `is:q` or `created`) you can find them among [Advanced Search Options](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the help center or by clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" after [performing any search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=).
- [How can I search questions asked a specific period of time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29402)
- [Searching for questions asked between two dates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19463)
- [How does one search for questions and answer by specific user and by date?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25386)
- [Access to question posts from previous years.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28512)